# How do I connect a Flask container to a Postgresql container in a docker-compose file?

Tags: docker-compose

I am getting extremely frustrated. I am trying to connect a flask website to a PostgreSQL database.
I made the postgresql db its own container, and have tried all the ways I can think of connecting to it.
To keep it simple, my flask file has the config which has the uri like so:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://user:password@0.0.0.0:5432/db'
```

I have tried `localhost, 0.0.0.0, and 127.0.0.1` none of which work, which makes sense. Since, the postgresql db is another container, they can not connect on localhost. they need to be connected.

The relevant part of my `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      db_network:
        aliases:
           - "pdb"

  webapp:
    build: .
    depends_on: [db]
    environment:
      - DEBUG=False
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - db_network

networks:
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Okay, no errors. So now I try my URI as `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://user:password@pwd:5432/db'` but I get an error from webabb that it can not translate the hostname, name or service unknown. For the past couple days, I have either been getting errors about not being able to find it, or it can not connect.

1) I made sure to delete any local instance of postgresql
2) I got rid of my volume, I was not unsure if that was causing issues
3) I tried different ports
4) I tried quite a few suggestions here on SO about clearing out orphaned containers and what.

I did use network inspect but that did give a hard coded IP address to use which I would guess can change.
I am absolutely stumped. Can anyone give some pointers? I would love to fully wipe Postgresql then setup the network to get it working. Then I will add back the volume
To clarify, I do not have any sort of config files for postgres beyond what I am setting in the docker-compose file but I did have it working at some point in the past, so I figure I do not need any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname of postgres container will be same as the service name i.e., `db` according to your compose file.  So you need to use the connection string `postgresql://user:password@db:5432/db`

Comment: Already tried this and got error 'db' name or service not known.

Comment: So this worked. What I had wrong was probably that I had a volume mounted where I had password, user and what not set. So I had to exec in bin bash and change them then this worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use links to connect to other containers.

```
db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password

 webapp:
    build: .
    depends_on: [db]
    environment:
      - DEBUG=False
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    links:
      - "db:my_db"
```

so you can access **db service** with using **my_db** as the host name for the database.
hope this is help full.

Comment: pretty sure links are depreciated: see https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Comment: @DavidFrick thanks buddy.. I'm still using links. need to update myself.